# Raspberry Pi 3B+ Ethenet socket Orange LED flashing

Tags: pi-3b+, ethernet-port

I have this weird issue with my Raspberry Pi 3B+ where during normal operation, e.g. while running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` the command errors out saying it couldn't connect to the servers. At this point, the green LED on the ethernet socket isn't lit and the orange LED on the ethernet socket is blinking.

The pi doesn't respond to pings from other devices on the network during this failure mode. I suspect the NIC to be faulty. Am I right?

**EDIT:** Possibly on an unrelated note, the Broadcom and LAN7515 chips are both at 55 degrees C. Thermal shutdown occurs at 100 degrees C, right?